# .htaccess vs custom request URI handler and sef links

Tags: php, seo

Currently I use seo like this.

```
PHP: domain.com/index.php?page=account&do=forgotpassword
.htaccess: domain.com/account/forgotpassword.html
```

However, I want to write my own handler for it, or use any other existing handlers which does the following.

```
Handler: Check request URI, convert it back to normal.
--- Request URI: domain.com/?/account/forgotpassword.html
--- Converts to: domain.com/index.php?page=account&do=forgotpassword
.htaccess: RewriteRule (.*)$ ?/$1
```

1. Does PHP support such handlers? If so, could you give a link where I can see such handlers? (e.g Code Igniter's, if it exists.)
2. Does it have any effects on SEO side? (eg. Google ignores/likes links)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. PHP doesn't have it built-in. But frameworks usually have their own *routing* (that's how it's called) libraries: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html
2. Google doesn't care of what rewrites the url: `.htacess` or php, since there is absolutely no difference from a client's point of view.